# ReactJS - Create API endpoint

Tags: reactjs, api

I have a create-react-app which has the function of swapping languages. All content/text is for the moment stored in a `.JSON`-file in the `src`-directory. I would like to make this `.JSON`-file available on an API-endpoint on the same domain, for example I can fetch data on the URL:

```
www.mysite.com/api
```

Can I do this in React without converting my application to a NextJS-app? How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve that in a `create-react-app` is to place the JSON file in the `public` folder. Another option is using [mirage](https://miragejs.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/)